# Is it better to use a AFCI/ GFCI breaker in the panel or do to use a AFCI/ GFCI receptacle?

Tags: bathroom, circuit-breaker, gfci, afci

To protect a bathroom outlet, should I put an AFCI/GFCI breaker in the breaker box or do I put in an AFCI/GFCI receptacle?

Can a AFCI/GFCI receptacle be divided into 2 circuits with a 20A breaker for each side of the AFCI/GFCI receptacle?

Comment: Related question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/46669/43874

Comment: Please add detail to your question. It's not clear what you're asking, and if you meant to include a link to a product you haven't done so.

Comment: Personal preference as long as the circuit is protected.   I prefer to use a receptacle so that in the case where GFCI trips, I can deal with it while still in the bathroom.

Comment: @dabi That is perfectly fine for GFCI. But AFCI really should be as close as possible to the panel (best is in the panel instead of a regular breaker) in order to provide the maximum protection.

Comment: GFCi and AFCI are **different things**.  The differences matter.   A GFCI/AFCI receptacle would be stupid, because it would put the AFCI protection in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a breaker or an outlet.  It's up to you.  For outside outlets on my house I chose to use a breaker so I could use regular cheap outlets in the weather, but in the bathrooms I stuck with the outlet style because it was a direct replacement and I didn't have to mess around with the breaker panel again.

AFCI/GFCI outlets only have two sets of screws - Line and Load, so there is no little tab to break off and separate them into two circuits like on a standard outlet.  You can't feed them with 2 breakers.

Answer (score 2):

> To protect a bathroom outlet, should I put an AFCI/GFCI breaker in the breaker box or do I put in an AFCI/GFCI receptacle?

AFCI protects **wires in the walls** so you want it either in the panel or close to it.

GFCI protects **people** so breaker or first protected location is equally OK.

GFCI definitely needed for bathroom receptacles. AFCI not necessarily needed for bathroom.

> Can a AFCI/GFCI receptacle be divided into 2 circuits with a 20A breaker for each side of the AFCI/GFCI receptacle?

If you are asking about splitting top & bottom to two different circuits, I don't believe that is an option on typical AFCI or GFCI receptacles. Where a simple duplex receptacle as two sets of hot & neutral screw terminals that are connected when used with the tab in place (default factory configuration) and can be split by breaking/removing the tab, an AFCI or GFCI instead uses one set of terminals for **line** and the other for **load**. However, if you use a double-pole AFCI/GFCI breaker in your breaker panel and run a /3 cable to the receptacles then you can wire up a regular duplex receptacle in a split configuration to get 20 A on the top and 20 A on the bottom.

Comment: FWIW, my understanding is that bathrooms are one of the few rooms that don't yet require AFCI protection (per 2017 NEC). I can't seem to reason why you wouldn't want one there, however.

Comment: @Sam I suspect that part of the original reason for exempting bathrooms from AFCI is that since they have to have GFCI (the top location where GFCI **really** makes sense, besides kitchens), requiring both would be "too much". Except that they added kitchen & laundry rooms to the AFCI requirement, and it really isn't clear why bathrooms would be any different.