# Is it necessary to use GFCI receptacle with AFCI/GFCI combo breaker?

Tags: electrical

I was just reading about the dual GFCI and AFCI breakers. Is it then necessary to use a GFCI receptacle with these breakers, or is that redundant? Also, rather than just pushing a button in your bathroom to reset or test, do you need to go to your panel each time?

Comment: AFCI is not required for bathrooms (yet). As of the 2014 NEC, the only GFCI/AFCI overlap is in kitchens and laundry rooms.

Comment: I hope you're not confusing this with combination AFCI breakers which has nothing to do with GFCI protection but series and parallel arching.

Comment: This question is similar to another, but not quite a duplicate: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/37501/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-gfci-breaker-with-an-arc-fault-breaker/37504#37504. My answer there describes the difference between GFCI and AFCI.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a circuit where you need both AFCI and GFCI protection for some reason, yes, these breakers are fine to use, and no, you do not need additional GFI receptacles. That would be redundant and waste $$$.

Yes, you definitely would need to go to the breaker panel to reset a tripped breaker. There is no such thing as a "remote reset".

You also should test them once a month or so.